# Find residue of $f(z) = e^{\frac{1}{1+√z}}dz$ in the point $z = 1$ for all branches of $e^{\frac{1}{1+√z}}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, exponential-function, residue-calculus, branch-points

As is said in the title I would like to evaluate the residue of $f(z) = e^{\frac{1}{1+√z}}dz$ in the point $z = 1$ for all branches of $e^{\frac{1}{1+√z}}$.

This is new for me, but after reading some exercises I believe the method is to find the points $(1,w)$ on Riemann surface, for each of them find a local coordinate (or parameter? I'm not sure there's a difference), and then express our initial function in terms of that corrdinate.

If this is true and enough, I guess that here the points of that Riemann surface are $z_1 = (1,e^{\frac{1}{2}})$ and $(1,\infty)$. (If the exponential function has only one branch, which I'm not sure, since its inverse function has 2 branches).

I believe that $z$ is a local coordinate for both $z_1$ and $z_2$, by Theorem on implicit function. But how can we expand $f(z)$ with respect to $z$?

I believe this kind of exercise can be done quite quickly once we get the method, hence I hope you can help me understand it so I can do it again !

**Edit**

I may have found another way to evaluate this residue but I'm not sure either, so here is what I did:

I noted that $z$ is a pole of order 1 for $f(z)$ in the branch defined by $\sqrt{1} = - 1$, meaning that in this branch its residue could befound using the following formula:

$$res_{z = z_0}f(z) = \lim\limits_{z\to z_0}(z - z_0)f(z)$$ which equals $0$ here.

So this would mean that $res_{z = 1}f(z) = 0$ in the branch defined by $\sqrt{1} = - 1$ and just doesn't exist in the other branch. Is this correct?

@Gary ?

Thanks

Comment: $z=1$ is not a pole for either branch.

Comment: Indeed, but it is a branch point of $\sqrt{z}$ and thus also for $f(z)$

Comment: @Rhaena Residue makes sense only for isolated singularities. Also, what is $dz$ in the definition of $f(z)$?

Comment: You are right @Gary, to evaluate residue we consider singular points, but in the branch defined by $\sqrt{1} = - 1$, 1 is indeed a singular point for $f$.

Comment: @Rhaena As I said, residue makes sense for *isolated* singularities, i.e., removable singularities, poles or essential singularities. Branch points are singularities but are *not* isolated singularities.

Comment: Oooh that's a nuance I didn't get!

Comment: So just to be sure, this means that this question can't be solved? I mean that this residue doesn't really exist

Comment: @Gary Just so there's no confusion, $z = 1$ is not a branch point of $f(z)$, we can extend any branch of $f(z)$ to a function analytic in a punctured neighborhood of $z = 1$. $f(z)$ will coincide either with $e^{1/(1 + \sqrt z)}$ or with $e^{1/(1 - \sqrt z)}$ in that neighborhood, where $\sqrt z$ is the principal value of the square root. For the latter case, we can find the residue by taking $z = (1 - 1/w)^2$ and evaluating the integral over $|w| = r \geq 1$.

Comment: @Maxim You are absolutely right. I hade $z=0$ in my mind all the time and not $z=1$.