# Calculate $\int_{C} e^{\frac{z^2}{z^2-1}}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Calculate $$\int_{C} e^{\frac{z^2}{z^2-1}}dz$$ where $C$ is the circle of radius $3$ centered at $0$ oriented counter clockwise.

So I want to do this by finding $\operatorname{Res}(f,\infty)=-\operatorname{Res}(\frac{1}{z^2}f(\frac{1}{z}),0)$ and then use the residue theorem $\int_{c}f(z)dz=2\pi i \sum_{a_k} \operatorname{Res}(f,a_k)=-2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f,\infty)$.

So I used the expansion of $e^x$ centered at $0$, $$\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=\frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{(1/z)^2}{(1/z)^2-1}\right)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{1}{(1-z^2)}\right)^n}{z^2n!}.$$

But there doesn't seem to be any value of $n$ which will give me $z^{-1}$.

Comment: Just a clarification : Isn't the exponent in the last step supposed to be $\frac{1}{1-z^2}$ instead?

Comment: @AspiringMathematician I realize I made a mistake when I multiplied by $\frac{1}{z^2}$

Comment: The integral is $0$. The two facts (1) integrand is even in $z$ (2) contour $C$ is invariant under $z \to -z$ are enough to force the integral to vanish.

Comment: A more interesting question would be if the integrand were $\exp{\left ( z^2/(z-1)^2 \right )}$. It seems to me Matjematica cannot handle residues at essential singularities.

Comment: @RonGordon That one can be computed as in the comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4133723) by taking $z = \sqrt w/(\sqrt w - 1)$ with the principal value of the square root and showing that we can integrate over $|w - 1| = r \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, put $z=\frac{1}{w}$ so that $dz=-\frac{1}{w^2}dw$ with the contour $C': \lvert w\rvert=\frac{1}{3}$ oriented clockwise.

$$I=-\int_{|w|=1/3} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{1-w^2}}}{w^2}dw$$

Of all the singularities of the integrand above, only a pole of order 2 at $w=0$ lies within $C'$, so

$I=+2\pi i\times Res\left (\frac{e^{\frac{1}{1-w^2}}}{w^2}, w=0\right )=0$

Comment: Sorry how do you know that $Res(\frac{e^{\frac{1}{1-w^2}}}{w^2},w=0)=0$?

Comment: It is $[\frac{d}{dw}(w^2. f(w))]_{w=0}$ usi ng the formula for residue at pole of order $n$.